# Regex to remove urls from string c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code and the regular expression I am currently using does not appear to be catching any url I enter in standard format (www.google.com) as when it is displayed in a listbox, the URL is still there. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

```
e1.MessageBody = txtMessage.Text;
                Regex.Replace(e1.MessageBody, @"/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/", ""string.Empty);
```

Comment: can you show an example of what the original URL looks like and what you're expecting.. `www.google.com` is displayed really doesn't explain the issue.. perhaps you could use the string.Replace along with the `Uri.Query` or `Uri` Class you split and replace.. not understanding your question

Comment: I'm looking to completely remove the url, hence the use of string.empty, therefore it showing means the regex isn't catching and removing www.google.com

Comment: In the sample code you provided you're not assigning the result of the `Regex.Replace` to anything and `""string.Empty` is an invalid parameter.

Answer (score 3):

```
var msg = "ASD www.google.com EFIG";

msg = Regex.Replace(msg, @"((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)", string.Empty);
```

C# doesn't use the regex identifiers (the leading/trailing `/`) and you had extra quotes `"` by the `string.empty` parameter.